# Why do I have to use 's in some sentences?

Tags: possessives, orthography

For example: Brandon's house instead Brandon house.
How is that rule named, I'm trying to improve my English.

Comment: We call the use of the apostrophe and **s** the "Saxon genitive". There is a good question at the link in the comment above. (Another way to improve your English is to capitalize proper nouns like "English" and names like "Brandon", and also the first person pronoun **I**.)

Comment: In English, we ask *What is something called?* not *How is something called?*

Answer (score 1):

*'s* is being used to show possession. You are asking about the *possessive form*.

> The [possessive form](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/forming-possessive/) is used with nouns referring to people, groups of people, countries, and animals. It shows a relationship of belonging between one thing and another. To form the possessive, add apostrophe + s to the noun. If the noun is plural, or already ends in s, just add an apostrophe after the s.
>   Examples
>
> - the car of John = **John's car**
> - the room of the girls = **the girls' room**
> - clothes for men = **men's clothes**
> - the boat of the sailors = **the sailors' boat**
>
> Functions of the possessive
>   'Belonging to' or 'ownership' is the most common relationship the possessive expresses.
>   Examples
>
> - John owns a car. = It is John's car.
> - America has some gold reserves. = They are America's gold reserves.

So if you are trying to indicate that Brandon owns a/this house, then you should say

> 1. This is **Brandon's** house.

*Brandon house* (without the *'s*) is incorrect in most cases. It does not indicate possession.

If *Brandon House* is a proper noun, such as the name of a restaurant, then it could work.

> 2. This is Brandon House.

This essentially means *This is the restaurant called Brandon House*. Note that it does not mean the same as 1. It is possible that Brandon owns the restaurant, but 2 does not indicate this.

These are just a few details about the possessive to get you started.